# How to store array collection in asp.net viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

i have a custom control i need to store the array collection in the view state. array collection is circular scales. How to proceed further ?

```
public class CircularGauge : WebControl
    {
private CircularGaugeProperties model = new CircularGaugeProperties();

private List<CircularScales> scales = new List<CircularScales>();
[Browsable(true)]
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Circular Gauge Properties")]
        [Description("Scale values")]
        [JsonProperty("scales")]
        [MergableProperty(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public List<CircularScales> Scales
        {
            get
            {
                if (scales == null)
                {
                    scales = new List<CircularScales>();
                }
                return scales;
            }
        }
}
```

where circular scales have array collection as inner properties.then how can i need to bind the properties in the Circularscales for viewstate maintenance.

Answer (score 7):

```
 public List<CircularScales> Scales
 {
     get
     {
         if (ViewState["scales"] == null)
         {
             return new List<CircularScales>();
         }
         return (List<CircularScales>)ViewState["scales"];
     }
     set
     {
         ViewState["scales"] = value;
     }
 }
```

Useful [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.control.viewstate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about what viewstate is and how to use it corectly.